# Are Cursors used for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, transactions, cursors

I am aware that cursors (implicit or explicit) can be created for SELECT statements.

**But does cursors  (say implicit) also get created for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations. If they do what is there purpose.**

*To be clear about the question:* A SELECT statement can result in a million records and creating a insensitive(actual data is copied) cursor can be helpful to return results to the client as client scrolls forward or backward and can avoid sending all the data in a single network request. *And any other benefits worth mentioning are welcome.*
But with the write operations (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) is a cursor required, won't it be an overhead of resources even if concurrency is considered.? If the operation has to fail it would just fail early. Or is it that for transaction isolation they are required. So, atomicity  and consistency are guaranteed through the creation of cursor. (concurrency could be handled through combination of other mechanism like 2PL or MVCC etc, **but i am more focused about the role of cursors in transaction** for the moment )

So as it seems like transactions also need to be considered, **does every transaction result in the creation of a cursor (implicit). Or given other mechanisms exists to handle transactions (with and with out concurrency), cursor have no say at all or just limited role when dealing with transaction.**

Comment: Are you talking about cursors in PL/SQL or "cursors" that are created by Oracle on the backend and are essentially the same thing as a parsed statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, essentially am trying to get a hold of what cursors are and how they help. Won't be doing much PL/SQL but knowing will not hurt unless they are totally different from how SQL uses them

Answer (score 2):

Almost every statement has to create/open a cursor (even DDL statements). *A cursor is a pointer to a private SQL area that stores information about the processing of a SELECT or data manipulation language (DML) statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE).*

If you don't create an explicit cursor then an implicit cursor is used. The most useful and most-used attribute of an implicit cursor  is the `%ROWCOUNT` attribute, it returns the number of affected rows.

Have a look at these documents to get more information.

[Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

[SQL (Implicit) Cursor Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm)

Comment: thanks for the Oracle reference. Being an Oracle user,  these reference are highly relevant for me.